# Can anyone suggest some ideas for what I want to do here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite well versed in developing in PHP, HTML5 and CSS3 however when it comes to Javascript and Jquery I'm totally lost.

What I'm looking at doing is on my site I want to place a custom page that allows the users to select certain options which will be specified by me.

pretty much along the lines of:-

Question1?

Select one of 2 options.

option 1 moves along to question 2

however where option 2 then moves to a different question.

what I would like to do instead is to use Javascript instead so it could be question 1 select answer, then question 2 automatically populates underneath. and then depending on that answer and so on, until the end is reached.

I will include a little snippet below so it helps visualise the end goal that I am looking for:-

```
<?php 
$q1 = $_POST['q1'] ?? '';
$q2 = $_POST['q2'] ?? '';
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['q1] {
echo 'q2';
} else {
echo 'q20';
}
?>
```

The HTML would then be:-

```
<form name="script_path.ext" method="POST">
<span>Question 1?</span></br>
<select id="q1" name="q1">
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" 
value="Next">
```

obviously it would be better to use Jquery to do this as the amount of variables are going to grow as questions get added and could become an infinite loop of if_statements.

Comment: Yes I would be looking at it storing the answers to certain questions in a database but only displaying relevant questions as well as most answers are going to be simple yes / no answers however some will require end user input and others will need to pull other existing records in a different table. Pretty much where question 1 if answered yes will then display question 2 but if question 1 is answered no then it would need to pull say for example question 5 as the other questions would be irrelevant to that users requirements.

Comment: Do you want to catch get parameters with js and then autoselect the option? I haven't understand what you mean

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript frameworks on the front-end? You'd greatly benefit from state management, such that comes with React or Angular

Comment: I've not had any look with installing frameworks on my system all my coding work is done by freehand I tried installing ruby but it just doesn't behave well on this system.

Comment: Eh walk before you can run, you would probably be better off starting with JQuery

Comment: But if you want to store the answers in a db you need extra server side code. Do you want to catch the values to send them via ajax to the server side?